# JQuery - url location and click event

Tags: jquery, url, events, click

$('#head_menu a').click(function(){
       currentPage = document.location.hash.split('#')[1];
    });

```
<div id="head_menu">
    <a href="#order"><div>make order</div></a>
    <a href="#portfolio"><div>portfolie</div></a>
    <a href="#contacts"><div>contacts</div></a>
    <a href="#vacancies"><div>vacancies</div></a>
    <a href="#about"><div>about company</div></a>
</div>
```

So, when I'm clicking to the links in head_menu div I come into this handler. But one trouble: if url has, for example, #about hash, in handler I'll get 'about', not that, at what I've clicked. Could I get new url-hash in click-handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just look at the `href` attribute of the link that was clicked?

```
$('#head_menu a').click(function(){
   currentPage = this.href.split('#')[1];
});
```

Comment: you could also get the hash from the attribute... $(this).attr('hash'); but this includes the hash (#) as well.. this is nice sometimes if you need the hash for an ID somewhere on your page :P

Answer (score 2):

Don't understand question ;)

BTW:

Another person who insert `div` into `a`. "a" is inline element so it couldn't has Div (it is block elemennt)

Comment: Not true for HTML5 any more, `a` can wrap `div` and other block level elements: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links