# JQuery and PhoneGap - Listening for hyperlink clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I understand that if I have the specific URL I can write a script to redirect it externally, instead of opening it within the application. However, the application I am currently working on has a 35+ url links which I have no way of getting the URL in order to redirect to an external browser. I cannot get the URL/hyperlink because it is sitting within a description body where I am capturing the data from. So any type of parsing would be unstable at best.

Is there some type of Listener script I could write to capture the event, read the URL, and place it in a variable so I can redirect it outside of the application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can register a jquery event object to listen for an event like so:
    
     $( "body" ).click(function( event ) {
     $( "#log" ).html( "clicked: " + event.target.nodeName );
     });

- referenced here: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: In this example, does the #log represent a section of the html page? For example, the URL within the description of my page is located in the #page-content. Could I swap #log for #page-content and be correct?

Comment: Yes, following the standard page template structure (ref:http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html) you can assign id's to each body description. It will help you distinguish between your content when referring to your tags that have the anchors in them.

Comment: I implemented the above code to test and I displayed the output of the click on the page and it came up as "Clicked: B". So is it safe to say its not a string of "B" but rather the actually url?

Comment: refer to this posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511368/jquery-url-location-and-click-event

Comment: I tried this: $('#page-content').click(function(){
   currentPage = this.href.split('#')[1];
   $( "#page-region" ).html( "clicked: " + currentPage);
}); the function didn't produce any result. Any recommendations?